# Power in an electrical circuit

Tags: power-electronics

In the formula I = V / R it makes sense that in a circuit such as the one found in homes the amount of current as proportional to number of electrons passing through a slice of wire per unit time is proportional to the push of the voltage and inversely proportional to the resistance due to how much electricity the martial of the wire allows to pass and its length.

But then what is the point of multiplying I and V in P = IV. How do I interpret this equation taking it further than seeing it as the product of two quantities related by Ohm's law?

Thanks.

Comment: The point of multiplying I and V is *that is what you do to calculate the power*. We didn't choose I and V just because we felt like it, but because that's how the physics works. And beware I and V are only related by Ohm's law *for resistors*.

Answer (score 1):

If a current is flowing and there is a voltage difference present it **must** be dropped across a resistance. Passing a current through a resistance (and thus creating a voltage) dissipates power. The instantaneous power dissipated by a current flowing through given resistance is given by P = IV, (where V = IR).

NOTE: you could use P = I^2 * R but usually we measure voltage and current so it's easier to use use P = IV

> "But then what is the point of multiplying I and V in P = IV.

Consider a circuit with a battery and a single 1k resistor:

The current is the same everywhere in the circuit, but the voltage drop across the wire connecting either end of the battery is much lower than the voltage drop across the 1k resistor - and thus dissipates less power, **using P=IV we can calculate how much power was dissipated by a given circuit element.**

A useful application is in working out how hot an LDO regulator will get. If i regulate from 5V to 3.3V and need to draw 1 amp in total, I know that the regulation will drop 5-3.3V = 1.7V across the resistor in the IC which will produce P = 1.7V * 1A  => 1.7 watt of power. These parts will then have a degree per watt value in the data sheet so I know exactly how hot the part will get - which is a pretty important thing to know... Notice I didn't know the exact resistance inside the IC..

Comment: Why do you say *instantaneous* power. Is there another form of power? What is a 1k resistance, isn't a resistance measured I ohms?

Comment: Why do you say *instantaneous* power. Is there another form of power? What is a 1k resistance, isn't a resistance measured I ohms? Are the terms voltage drop and voltage interchangeable? So, I think I  understand the point of measuring the voltage difference across different parts of the wire, thus producing different values, for V, and thus P, despite I being the same. After all, since the current will be the same a everywhere in a circuit, measuring across different parts of three wire will change the resistance since the resistors and wire consistencies and lengths will change

Comment: across differeng parts of the circuit.

Comment: Interesting application of measuring the power in a specific part of the circuit to predict heat dissipation.

Comment: Electrical power can be time-varying either as a DC quantity or as an AC quantity. The amount of power in a circuit at any instant of time is called the instantaneous power and is given by the well-known relationship of P = VI.

Comment: Voltage drop is (to my mind) the voltage drop created by a resistive component due to a current through it. 

Voltage is the voltage difference measured  at a specific point with respect to ground.

Comment: 1k is short for a 1 kilo Ohm resistor.

Answer (score 1):

Energy lost when a charge q moves across a potential difference V is given by:
$$E = qV$$
If this charge took t time to cross this potential difference then power is:
$$P = \frac{E}{t} = \frac{qV}{t}$$
But the average charge flow per unit time is defined as current thus,
$$P = IV$$
This energy/power lost by the carriers gets converted to heat for a resistor in thermal equilibrium.

In microscopic terms the current through a conductor is given by:
 $$I = neAv_d,$$ where n is the electron density in the conductor, e is the charge on the electron and \$v_d\$ is the drift velocity which is the average velocity of the electron due to the electric field.
q thus depends on the free charge concentration of the conductor.
Potential difference is the potential energy per unit charge so total energy is charge q time the potential difference.

Comment: This answer was very helpful. Textbooks should really start with the equation I = q/t before moving on to Ohm's Law. I wonder whether you could be so kind as to explain how to interpret energy in the equation E = qV. I know the greater the voltage the greater the force used to push three electrons through the circuit, presumably the greater the number of electrons passing per unit time in a way that is inversely proportional to resistance since I = V / R, and the greater the source battery gets consumed, the more heat generated in the wires. Maybe you can explain this last point better.

Comment: In E = qV, what does the quantity q of Coulombs represent (I know a Coulomb is just a certain fixed number of electrons)?

Comment: I have added the explanation, hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

To use the water metaphor, the amount of energy in the flow of a river is related to both the speed of the flow (vaguely equivalent to voltage) and the depth (vaguely equivalent to current).  To determine energy you have to look at both.

If you have no current, it doesn't matter what the voltage is - no work is being done.  With no voltage, you cannot have any current flow so there is no work being done then either.

Comment: Well the speed of the flow would also have to be equivalent to resistance wouldn't it? The higher the resistance, the lower the speed, so why not P = IV / R? Thanks.

Comment: @JimmyJoslington - it takes more power to push something with high resistance than the reverse. So if you are pushing a given flow through higher resistance, higher power is required. (And given the same current, for higher resitance you need higher voltage)